# ERROR: PROTOC FAILED: google/protobuf/wrappers.proto: File not found. (Error in Maven build)

Tags: grpc-java, protoc

I was trying to build a grpc service using the following plugin. Seems like the plugin is not able to use protoc utility.

OS : MAC

Maven version : 3.6.3

Error :

```
[ERROR] PROTOC FAILED: google/protobuf/wrappers.proto: File not found.
order-mgmt.proto: Import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto" was not found or had errors.
order-mgmt.proto:7:16: "google.protobuf.StringValue" is not defined.

...
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (default) on project OrderManagement-gRPC: protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. -> [Help 1]**
```

The plugin i am using is :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact> </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `protobuf-java` dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

Here is how I use the plugin.

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.1</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.5.1-1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>test-compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then use the `mvn protobuf:compile` to generate the stubs. The reference is from the plugin repo at https://github.com/xolstice/protobuf-maven-plugin

Comment: Yes i wasnt giving the correct grpc version and that was not in sync with dependencies i added. Basically The versions of grpc and protobuf in dependency and plugins used should be in sync. So better to use in properties and avoid using it directly. Thanks !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Providing the pom :

To keep in mind the proto and grpc versions. They should be in sync. Better to declare them in properties tag, so that we dont commit any version mismatch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.practice</groupId>
<artifactId>OrderManagement-gRPC</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<grpc.version>1.35.0</grpc.version>
<protoc.version>3.4.0</protoc.version>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>${protoc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>Displaying 1 environment variables</echo>
                            <echo>[Path] ${env.PATH}</echo>
                            <echo>[os.detected.classifier] ${os.detected.classifier}</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact> </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

      
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem without "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto: File not found."
It was because I ran this plugin on Windows machine without admin access